# To replace two pieces of text do I need to do str_replace twice?

Tags: php, refactoring

Is there a better function that will do this than what I'm doing?  I need to get rid of both `<div>` and `</div>` if they are in the strings.  I'm doing this.  It works, but it seems ugly to me:

```
$cdsHtml .= str_replace('</div>','', str_replace('<div>', '', sprintf('<p><strong>%s</strong><br>%s<br>%s</p>', $cd->Name, $cd->Description, $cd->Prereq)));
```

Is there one function that will replace both of those `str_replace`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can replace more than one string by pass an array of values into the first parameter in str_replace

```
$cdsHtml .= str_replace(array('</div>','<div>'),'',  sprintf('<p><strong>%s</strong><br>%s<br>%s</p>', $cd->Name, $cd->Description, $cd->Prereq));
```